# Render position does not match layout position

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a custom dropdown element that is positioned fixed and works in Firefox and Chrome. But in Edge the layout position does not match to the render position (see image). The marked element is the form with the Text+Filter+Order. It has a strange render offset. The element has no transformations. If you click to the window where the checkbox or input elements should be it works correctly.

Any ideas what could go wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you try to provide a sample code then we can try to make a test with MS Edge and try to produce the issue. Then we can try to provide any solution or work around.

Comment: I created a bug report where you can reproduce it, but I can not reproduce it with a simple sample yet.